# Azure App Configuration Tags not showing up in Cost Analysis

Tags: azure, cost-management, azure-app-configuration

We have an Azure App Configuration deployed in our subscription and we have put 2 tags to every resource ('costType' and 'environment'). All resources are tagged and appearing when we pull the Cost Analysis report by Tags except the App Configuration. They show the Tags column as blank. Is this expected behavior or a bug in Azure cost analysis?

As a side note: the tags were applied several weeks ago, while the cost analysis was run for the last week.

Additionally, in cost analysis the location of App Configuration is shown as 'US west' even though the location set to 'EU west' on the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The billing support for resource tags is not available at this point. Please feel free to open an issue in the GitHub repo (https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues) of Azure App Configuration so you can get updated when the support is added in the future.

We will also look into the billing location issue. Please feel free to open a separate issue for that in our GitHub repo too.